# how to set the contents of an array equal to the contents from a second array

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception, greedy

I'm using greedy algorithm to calculate change, I want to save the set of the coins i've used to a new aray, however I :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at lacy_lab_7b_2015.Lacy_Lab_7b_2015.main(Lacy_Lab_7b_2015.java:36)
Java Result: 1
```

from the complier.

```
    public class Lacy_Lab_7b_2015 {

public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);// scanner object to allow user input
public static int amount;// global variable defined by user to be used to have certain value of coins added so that they wll equal this value
public static int count = 0;
final public static int[] FACE_VALUES_OF_COINS = {100, 50, 25, 10, 5, 1};
public static int[] coinsUsed;

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    amount = userAmount();
   // coinsUsed = coinsUsed(FACE_VALUES_OF_COINS,amount);

    for (int i = 0; i < FACE_VALUES_OF_COINS.length; i++) {
        int j = 0;
        if (FACE_VALUES_OF_COINS[i] < amount) {
            int count = amount / FACE_VALUES_OF_COINS[i];
           coinsUsed[j] = FACE_VALUES_OF_COINS[i];
            amount -= count * FACE_VALUES_OF_COINS[i];
        }//end if
    }//end for
    for (int i = 0; i < coinsUsed.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(coinsUsed[i]);
    }
}//end main
```

Comment: 36            amount -= count * FACE_VALUES_OF_COINS[i];

Comment: but on mine its line 35 and that line is :   coinsUsed[j] = FACE_VALUES_OF_COINS[i];

Comment: Where do you define `FACE_VALUES_OF_COINS`?

Comment: did you declare and assigned coinUsed array

Comment: final public static int[] FACE_VALUE_OF_COINS = {100, 50, 25, 10, 5, 1};

Comment: yes above the main method as a global variable

Comment: you just declared coinUsed as array but you did'nt assigned it with vaues?  so at statement  coinsUsed[j] = FACE_VALUES_OF_COINS[i]; compiler doesnt knew what is coinsUsed[0]

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

I whould suggest you to write

public static int[] coinsUsed;

as

public static int[] coinsUsed = new int[5];